# Is there a Rails way to namespace controllers without namespacing urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to be able to namespace my controllers, without namespacing the urls. So for example, I'd like to be able to have a controller in a folder like:

```
app/controllers/abc/my_controller
```

and another in

```
app/controllers/def/my_controller
```

I don't want the routes to contain /abc, or /def, instead I'm using constraints to disambiguate between them. What's the most Rails way to achieve this?

Some background: I'm building a multi-domain site, the constraint is the request domain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a scope with a block.

```
scope :module => "abc" do
  resources :my_controller
end

scope :module => "def" do
  resources :my_controller
end
```

or pass it individually

```
resources :my_controller, :module => "abc"
resources :my_controller, :module => "def"
```

More information in the [routes guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing). The information on scopes is just under the table in the section I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

routes.rb:

`resources :resource_name, module: 'ControllerNameSpace', constraints: {subdomain: 'foo'}`

[Rails guide link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)